# Using ILogger<T> without constructor injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ilogger, servicecollection

I have my registration and constructor setup to use logging via Microsoft.Extensions.Logging as follows,

`public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger) {}`

What I'd like to do, though, is use `services.AddSingleton()` in my Startup.cs to avoid using constructor injection.  The reason is that it will otherwise require modifying all unit tests to Mock the logger when testing the service.
I believe there's a way to register the specific instance of ILogger in the ServiceCollection, but I cannot sort out the syntax required.

Thanks!

Comment: `ILogger` must never be registered as `Singleton` though.

Comment: "The reason is that it will otherwise require modifying all unit tests to Mock the logger when testing the service." - but *that's the point* - if you don't care about what gets logged in a test then use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.NullLoggerFactory`.

Comment: @Dai Thanks so much, I wasn't aware of that abstraction.  That solves my problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In unit tests you should not be using a DI container.

  - If you were, then you're writing an integration test, not a unit test.
- In unit tests, generally speaking, the *arrange* part of the test should set-up your SUT by directly invoking SUT's constructor and passing-in test/mock/stub versions of its dependencies.
- In unit tests, ideally you should supply an entire *testing-implementation* of the entire `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider` interface (and related classes) which will allow you to assert that specific log output messages were written, or to redirect `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>` output to your test's own output.

  - Unfortunately this isn't in-box (and [Microsoft won't release their own](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/672)), but there are many popular libraries for this:

    - https://github.com/martincostello/xunit-logging
    - https://github.com/alefranz/MELT
- Alternatively, if your tests aren't concerned with asserting `ILogger` usage and/or if you don't want your SUT's own log output written to your test output, [then use `NullLoggerFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nullloggerfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) or `NullLogger<T>.Instance` in your *arrange* section to create a stub `ILogger<T>` that doesn't do anything.

Like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;

// [...]

[Fact]
public void MyService_should_do_something()
{
    // Arrange:

    IArbitraryDependency dep         = new StubArbitraryDependency();
#if FULL_MOON_TONIGHT
    ILogger<MyService>   nullLogger  = NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<MyService>();
#else
    ILogger<MyService>   nullLogger  = NullLogger<MyService>.Instance();
#endif

    MyService systemUnderTest = new MyService(
        arbitraryDependency: dep,
        logger             : nullLogger
    );

    // Act:

    systemUnderTest.DoSomething();

    // Assert:
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Yep, that worked perfectly, thanks!  My setup looks like this now and is just what I needed, `var service = new MyService(_mockDate.Object, NullLogger<IMyService>.Instance);`

Comment: Ooooh, I didn't know you could skip `NullLoggerFactory` and just use `NullLogger<IMyService>.Instance` directly - I'll update my answer.